# Webform - Multilingual Support

Tags: nodes, webforms, i18n-l10n, forms

I have a webform which is built in English. I need to add two more languages. Is that possible to display many languages in webform?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Webform Localization](https://drupal.org/project/webform_localization) module

> The Webform Localization module provides multilingual features to the Webform Module. Special options in the webform and component configuration let you enable different ways to manage translation of forms and questionnaires.

Comment: Does Webform localization supports drupal 6.x ? also i just need to replicate the drupal webform node to another two more languages. is that possible?

Comment: @user24393 Are you using drupal v6? Then why didn't you add it to the tags?

Comment: http://wunderkraut.com/blog/quick-and-dirty-translation-of-field-labels-in-webforms/2011-11-19 - the first link on google search.